# QueryOver and null check on optional reference

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have a User with a 1-1 relation to optional UserData. They are sharing the same identifier in the db.

```
User
 Id(x => Id, "id")
 References<UserData>(x => x.UserData, "id");

UserData
 Id(x => Id, "id")
```

I would like to query all users with no optional data.
But this query makes the null check on the User ID column.

```
var list = session.QueryOver<User>()
   .Where(x => x.UserData != null)
```

This is also the case if i use HasOne.

Comment: Are you saying the generated SQL is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your mapping is something like this :

```
    public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Table("UserTable");
            Id(x=>x.Id).Column("Id");
            HasOne(x => x.Data);
        }
    }

    public class UserDataMap : ClassMap<UserData>
    {
        public UserDataMap()
        {
            Table("UserDataTable");
            Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id");
            Map(x=>x.DataText).Column("DataText");

        }
    }
```

You may try :

```
        UserData userDataAlias = null;

        var results = session.QueryOver<User>()
            .Left.JoinQueryOver(x=>x.Data,()=>userDataAlias)
            .WhereRestrictionOn(y=>y.Id).IsNull
            .List();
```

The resulting query with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `IS NULL` clause would then be like the following :

```
SELECT
        this_.Id as Id14_1_,
        userdataal1_.Id as Id13_0_,
        userdataal1_.DataText as DataText13_0_ 
    FROM
        UserTable this_ 
    left outer join
        UserDataTable userdataal1_ 
            on this_.Id=userdataal1_.Id 
    WHERE
        userdataal1_.Id is null
```